# Order column varchar with multiple dots. Like number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want help for ordering the column (Parent) like number 4.1 -> 4.2 -> 4.9 -> 4.10

```
ColA  ColB  Parent(varchar(max))
             1
             1.1      
             1.22
             2
             2.1
             3
             3.1
             3.1.1
             3.1.2.1
             3.1.2.12
             4.4
             4.4.1
             4.4.10
             4.4.11
             4.4.2
             4.4.3
```

select colA, colB, Parent
from myTable
ORDER BY Parent

Comment: What is the maximum depth?

Comment: maximum is 4 blocks. Example: x.x.x.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this simple solution -**

```
CREATE TABLE sorts
(
    Parent varchar(max)
)
GO

INSERT INTO sorts VALUES
('1'),
('1.1'),
('1.22'),
('2'),
('2.1'),
('3'),
('3.1'),
('3.1.1'),
('3.1.2.1'),
('3.1.2.12'),
('4.4'),
('4.4.1'),
('4.4.10'),
('4.4.11'),
('4.4.2'),
('4.4.3')
GO
SELECT Parent FROM sorts
ORDER BY CAST('/'+REPLACE(Parent,'.','/')+'/' AS HIERARCHYID)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Parent
-------------------
1
1.1
1.22
2
2.1
3
3.1
3.1.1
3.1.2.1
3.1.2.12
4.4
4.4.1
4.4.2
4.4.3
4.4.10
4.4.11

(16 rows affected)
```

**Read more from here -**
https://msbiskills.com/2015/10/12/sql-puzzle-sort-data-by-version-puzzle/

Comment: Nice solution! Learned something today :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is another option for this. Note that this will not work if you have depth more than 4.

I am using the same table that Pawan Kumar posted. I ran this against a much larger dataset (1.8 million rows) and the performance of the two stayed the same. Even the execution plans are identical which I found rather surprising.

```
select Parent 
from sorts
order by PARSENAME(Reverse(Parent), 1)
    , PARSENAME(Reverse(Parent), 2)
    , PARSENAME(Reverse(Parent), 3)
    , PARSENAME(Reverse(Parent), 4)
```